# What is the complexity of generating bell numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, computational-complexity

I want to know the complexity of generating the bell numbers and also want to know the nature of this problem (NP-complete, NP-hard, etc).

Comment: There is no "worst-case" here as there is a single case. The problem is obviously polynomial.

Comment: There are algorithms and asymptotics on the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will update my question regarding the worst-case complexity.

Comment: Thanks @EthanBolker but I have not found a discussion about the complexity issue in the link that you provide.

Comment: you can do it in quadratic time with the recursion

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo: how ? Do you count constant-time additions ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust yeah, I was counting constant time addition

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo: I confirm an $\Omega(n^2\log n)$ lower bound.

Comment: wow, how?${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo: hem, my answer maybe ?

Answer (score 3):

By the "triangle scheme", very similar to Pascal's triangle, you compute the $n^{th}$ row from the $(n-1)^{th}$ with $n$ additions so this method involves $O(n^2)$ additions.

As there are $n$ numbers to generate, and the asymptotic value of the logarithm (i.e. the number of digits; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Growth_rate) is $\Theta(n\log n)$, the trivial lower bound of the complexity is $\Omega(n^2\log n)$. And by the previous argument, an upper bound is $O(n^3\log n)$.

---

This site http://fredrikj.net/blog/2015/08/computing-bell-numbers/ is much advanced on the topic and reports computation of the $n^{th}$ number to be doable in $n^{2+o(1)}$, and the same bound for the computation of the $n$ first numbers.

This is not compatible with my $\Omega(n^2\log n)$ lower bound.

Comment: Another possibility is to recursively generate the Stirling subset numbers (which has the same complexity); summing these will yield the Bell numbers.

Comment: @J.M.: do you know the complexity of computing the Stirling numbers ?

Comment: Using [the usual recurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Recurrence_relation), about the same amount of effort as computing binomial coefficients.

Comment: @J.M.: so why do you consider the Stirling mumbers ? And what's the complexity of computing the binomial coefficients ?

Comment: You did mention $O(n^2)$ effort.

Comment: @J.M.: this is just an upper bound on the number of additions. There is a large gap to the lower bound.